# Convert and replace '%Y%m%d%H%M' to a datetime in a dictionary of dataframes

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, dictionary, dataframe

Hello I am looking to convert a '%Y%m%d%H%M' to a datetime and replace it in a dictionary of dataframes.

```
import pandas as pd
import time

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data= {'col1':['201706202359' , '201706220510'], "col2" : ['0', '1']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data= {'col1':['201707202300' , '201706230600'],"col2" : ['0', '1']})


dfs = {'df1' : df1, 'df2' : df2}

for name, df in dfs.items():

    for i in range(len(df)):
        timestamp = time.strptime(str(df[["col1"]].iloc[i][0]), '%Y%m%d%H%M')
        datetime = pd.to_datetime((str(timestamp[2])+"-"+str(timestamp[1])+"-"+str(timestamp[0])+" "+ str(timestamp[3])+":"+ str(timestamp[4])+":"+ str(timestamp[5])))
```

But I can't replace the converted `col1` which is now a timestamp in `col1`.
How can I do such a thing.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC:

```
In [330]: for x in dfs:
     ...:     dfs[x]['col1'] = pd.to_datetime(dfs[x]['col1'], format='%Y%m%d%H%M')
     ...:

In [331]: dfs
Out[331]:
{'df1':                  col1 col2
 0 2017-06-20 23:59:00    0
 1 2017-06-22 05:10:00    1, 'df2':                  col1 col2
 0 2017-07-20 23:00:00    0
 1 2017-06-23 06:00:00    1}

In [332]: dfs['df1']
Out[332]:
                 col1 col2
0 2017-06-20 23:59:00    0
1 2017-06-22 05:10:00    1
```

Be aware that it has also changed original DFs:

```
In [340]: df1
Out[340]:
                 col1 col2
0 2017-06-20 23:59:00    0
1 2017-06-22 05:10:00    1

In [341]: df2
Out[341]:
                 col1 col2
0 2017-07-20 23:00:00    0
1 2017-06-23 06:00:00    1
```

Comment: Thank you it worked for my sample example. I am using it for my real dataset.

Comment: @Amy21, please let me know how it works for your real data set

Comment: @Amy21, glad i could help :)